# Create variable name based on argument sent to function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create variable name based on value sent to function in javascript.
like following, when i call function variable : variable("zebra"); this should return variable name as zebra1

```
function create variable(i){
return i+"1";
}
var variable("zebra")="abc";//this line should create variable zebra1 and initialise as abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window['zebra'] = 'abc';
```

The window object holds all the global variables, assuming this is a request for global variables.

**To specifically answer your question**, you could put `return window[i + '1'] = 'abc';` in your variable naming function.

Alternatively, you could create a global (or local) object named `variables` to hold all your variables:

```
function whoknows() {
  var variables = {};
  variables['zebra'] = 'abc';
}
```

Read more on [working with objects at mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can create global variable with

```
 window["zebra"] = "abc";
```

and use later ether with the same indexer syntax or directly - `zebra`.